# FFMPEG encrypt & decrypt Video offline

Tags: encryption, video, ffmpeg, offline

I want encrypt & decrypt Video file With FFMPEG oflfine mode in hard disk.

I encrypt a Video File (mp4 Extention) by ffmpeg.exe Tools by this Command:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy
-encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key
76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid
a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb_encrypted.mp4
```

for decryption :
i want decrypt and play video file (encrypted.mp4) in my player source c++
(ffmpeg base) and *now i dont wnat use decrypt file with command line with
ffplay.exe *like this :

```
ffplay SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb_encrypted.mp4 -decryption_key
76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb
```

**how i can do decrypt with Write programing code that use FFMPEG api?**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure to check out the [how to ask page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You should try including what you've tried already, and why it doesn't work. That makes it easier to find your problem.